# C++ chat system

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, chat

I am able to make client and server connect, but not chat with each other. I can only make the server receive messages and the client can only to send them...but it doesn't work the other way around.

**Relevant server code:**

```
    while(recv(acceptedSocket,buffer,255,0)){
        std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
        memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
        n = send(acceptedSocket,"Message received!", 18 , 0);
        if(n < 0)
            error("Failed sending data!");
    }
```

**Relevant client code:**

```
    do{
        memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
        std::cout << "Enter your message: " << std::endl;
        std::cin.getline(buffer,255);
        n = send(connectingSocket,buffer,strlen(buffer),0);
    } while(n > 0);
```

Can I make server and client send and receive messages without multi-threading or do I have to multi-thread?

**All code**
**Server:**

```
    int main() {

        int listeningSocket,acceptedSocket,port,n;
        unsigned int clientLength;
        char buffer[256];
        struct sockaddr_in server_address , client_address;
        std::cout << "ENTER PORT(ABOVE 2000):";
        std::cin >> port;
        if(port < 2000){
            error("NO PORT PROVIDED");
        }
        listeningSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
        if(listeningSocket < 0)
            error("FAILED CREATING A SOCKET!");
        memset((char * ) &server_address,0,sizeof(server_address));
        server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        server_address.sin_port = htons(port);
        if(bind(listeningSocket,(struct sockaddr *) &server_address,sizeof(server_address)) < 0)
            error("BINDING FAILED!");
        listen(listeningSocket,5);
        clientLength = sizeof(client_address);
        acceptedSocket = accept(listeningSocket,(struct sockaddr *) &client_address,&clientLength);
        if(acceptedSocket < 0)
            error("ACCEPTING FAILED!");
        std::cout << "Connection incoming from " << client_address.sin_addr.s_addr << std::endl;
        while(recv(acceptedSocket,buffer,255,0)){
            std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
            memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
            n = send(acceptedSocket,"Message received!", 18 , 0);
            if(n < 0)
                error("Failed sending data!");
        }
    }
```

**Client:**

```
int main() {
    int connectingSocket,portNo,n;
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    struct hostent *server;
    char buffer[256];
    std::cout << "Enter server's IP:";
    char * ipHolder;
    std::cin >> ipHolder;
    server = gethostbyname(ipHolder);
    if(server == NULL){
        error("NO SUCH HOST!");
    }
    std::cout << "ENTER PORT:";
    std::cin >> portNo;
    connectingSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(connectingSocket < 0)
        error("FAILED OPENING A SOCKET!");
    memset(&server_address,0,sizeof(server_address));
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(portNo);
    memcpy(server->h_addr_list,&server_address.sin_addr.s_addr,server->h_length);
    if(connect(connectingSocket,(sockaddr *)&server_address,sizeof(server_address)) < 0)
        error("CONNECTION FAILURE!");
    std::cout << "CONNECTION MADE!" << std::endl;
    std::cin.ignore();
    do{
        memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
        std::cout << "Enter your message: " << std::endl;
        std::cin.getline(buffer,255);
        n = send(connectingSocket,buffer,strlen(buffer),0);
    }while(n > 0);

    return 0;
 }
```

Thank you!

Comment: No, you don't need to multi-thread. A good C/C++ example source is to take a look at http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm.

Comment: sometimes it helps to flush the buffer

Comment: I have done my code using this guide.

Comment: @ESipalis - that's a pity, it's not a very good guide:(

Answer (score 0):

The easiest most straight-forward solution is making the server/client send a message and right after that make it wait for a reply from the other, like that:

server:

```
while(recv(acceptedSocket,buffer,255,0)){  //here you read a message
        std::cout << "clients message: " << buffer << std::endl;  //print it on screen
        memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
        /*
             instead of sending "message recieved" to server, try to get
             some message from the user using cin maybe
             and send() what the user has entered
             then loop over and get another message
        */
        std::cin.getline(buffer,255); //get user's message
        //don't forget to find out buffer length
        n = send(acceptedSocket, buffer, buffer_len , 0); //send the message
        if(n < 0)
            error("Failed sending data!");
        //client has got the message now, you loop and wait for his reply
    }
```

client:

```
do{
        memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
        std::cout << "Enter your message: " << std::endl;
        std::cin.getline(buffer,255);  //get message
        n = send(connectingSocket,buffer,strlen(buffer),0); //send it to server
        /*
            recv() from the connecting socket and print the message
            when you loop over, the server has your message, user enters 
            another one, and the client waits for the message, and then 
            sends something the user entered
        */
        recv(connectingSocket,buffer,255,0); //wait for server's user reply
        std::cout << "server's message: " << buffer << std::endl;
        //you have now recieved server's message, you loop over and you're ready to send his another one
    } while(n > 0);
```

So like this, you have to wait for a reply, you cannot send 2(+) messages i a row.

I have not tested this, but it's a rough idea of what it might look like :)

Comment: Yeah,I had done similiar thing,but it doesn't work for me,I need to work it normally,so you can send messages and receive(Same time).So I guess, I need to use multi-threading?

Comment: Note that recv() offers a return value that you cannot refuse.  You must correctly action values of less than 0, 0 and greater than 0, all of which mean something very important.  Same with all syscalls, really..

Answer (score 0):

I did two different programs and it works on same computer or different ones on the network...

Have fun... this is what I started with...  looking at yours, there are a number of concerns... so cut and past and play with this server and client.

```
//Echo Server and Client using Berkley Socket Primitives
// Server
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

  char                         buffer[128]; 
  int                           sinlen;
  struct sockaddr_in    sin; 
  int                           s, h; 

  sin.sin_family = AF_INET; 
  sin.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  sin.sin_port = htons(888);   // Port 888
                                         // SOCK_STREAM is TCP
  s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0);
                                        // Bind socket to local port
  bind(s,(struct sockaddr*)&sin,sizeof(sin));
                                        // Listen for 1 connection
  listen(s,1);
  sinlen = sizeof(sin);      
                                        // 1. Block for connection
  h=accept(s,(struct sockaddr*)&sin,&sinlen );
                                        // 2. Block for receive
  recv(h,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0); 
                                        // 3. Echo received data
  send(h,buffer,strlen(buffer),0);

  close(h);

  return 0;
}



// Client
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

  char                         buffer[128]= "Hello world"; 
  struct sockaddr_in      sin; 
  struct hostent           *host; 
  int                           s; 

  host = gethostbyname("localhost");  

  memcpy(&(sin.sin_addr), host->h_addr,host->h_length); 
  sin.sin_family = host->h_addrtype; 
  sin.sin_port = htons(888);
                                               // Create socket port 888
  s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0);
                                               // 1. Block for server accept
  connect(s,  (struct sockaddr*)&sin,sizeof(sin));     
                                               // 2. Send "Hello world"       
  send(s,buffer,strlen(buffer)+1,0);   
                                               // 3. Block for receive 
  recv(s,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0);
                                               // Print received data
  NSLog(@"Received %s\n",buffer); 

  close(s);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: No.  Use of NSLog call on a buffer that is not guaranteed null-terminated.  recv() returns a value - use it!

Comment: Doesn't this just send one message and server sends it back.Also this doesn't check for any errors,so if binding fails or opening a socket,won't you have a problem?

Comment: This is to build off of... once you have something that sends and receives correctly, than you can expand upon that.  Just put the send and recv in a loop on both the client and server.  This is setup up for blocking for the receive... so it will wait for a message before doing the next line.   

Sorry about the NSLog... this was for the mac.

Comment: On the client, you are missing the receive portion.  So your talking will be messed up there for starters.

Comment: And after the receive you will have to flush the buffer:  fflush(stdout);

Comment: I did it that way,because I want to send and receive messages at the same time,while yours have to send first before it can receive.Also,I already flush my buffer on server code.